# How do I build the grails audit-logging-plugin? I get ModelBuildingException

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-plugin, audit-logging

I have downloaded the grails audit-logging-plugin and expanded the zip. Then I installed Gradle.
When I try to run any command

I get the following error
    H:\git\grails-audit-logging-plugin> c:\gradle-2.6\bin\gradle test

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/gradle/mvn3/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingException
> org.gradle.mvn3.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.07 secs
```

Below is what I see when I run it with the --stacktrace option
H:\git\grails-audit-logging-plugin> c:\gradle-2.6\bin\gradle test --stacktrace

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/gradle/mvn3/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingException
> org.gradle.mvn3.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/mvn3/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingException
        at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.class$(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
        at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.$get$$class$io$spring$gradle$dependencymanagement$mave
n$EffectiveModelBuilder(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
        at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.apply(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy:79)
        at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin.apply(DependencyManagementPlugin.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator$5.run(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:125)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugin(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:154)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:123)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:495)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:89)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:103)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)

        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java
:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java
:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.mvn3.org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException
        ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 19.173 secs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at this if its helpful: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/54

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this with the following version of the plugin.

```
classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE"
```

**e.g :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

[More info](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/54)

Hope this helps.